# What are good examples of: "operation of a program should map input values to output values rather than change data in place"

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I came across this sentence in Scala in explaining its **functional behavior**.

> *operation of a program should  map input of values to output values rather than change data in place*

Could somebody explain it with a good example?

**Edit:**  Please explain or give example for the above sentence in its context, please do not make it complicate to get more confusion

Comment: Another name for what you are asking about is "referential transparency". It means that a function should always receive sufficient context in it's input parameters such that when the function operates, it does not modify the input parameters, it requires no additional "global" context and will return a specific output. In addition, it also guarantees that if the same function is called with the exact same input parameters, the exact same output can be expected and will be received. This then supports the next higher notion, composability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it's the difference between:

```
var counter = 0
def updateCounter(toAdd: Int): Unit = {
  counter += toAdd
}
updateCounter(8)
println(counter)
```

and:

```
val originalValue = 0
def addToValue(value: Int, toAdd: Int): Int = value + toAdd
val firstNewResult = addToValue(originalValue, 8)
println(firstNewResult)
```

This is a gross over simplification but fuller examples are things like using a foldLeft to build up a result rather than doing the hard work yourself: [foldLeft example](http://seanparsons.github.com/scalawat/Fold+To+The+Left.html)

Comment: Good example. I understood what does that sentence exactly mean from your example. thank you so much. Can you exactly say how does that explanation in the sentence and the example you had given relates functional programming.

Comment: The foldLeft is a better example of functional programming as it would be trivial to take the result from a foldLeft and pass it in as the seed value for another foldLeft or any other function. As we know what the state of that value is, we can reason better about the end result. Whereas with some random mutable variable, anything else could've altered the value in the meantime.

Comment: Sufficed to say, it can be hard to see why this is a good thing without implementing things in a functional way using immutable variables.

Answer (score 14):

The most obvious pattern that this is referring to is the difference between how you would write code which uses collections in Java when compared with Scala. If you were writing scala but in the *idiom of Java*, then you would be working with collections by mutating data in place. The *idiomatic* scala code to do the same would favour the mapping of input values to output values.

Let's have a look at a few things you might want to do to a collection:

### Filtering

In Java, if I have a `List<Trade>` and I am only interested in those trades executed with *Deutsche Bank*, I might do something like:

```
for (Iterator<Trade> it = trades.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Trade t = it.next();
    if (t.getCounterparty() != DEUTSCHE_BANK) it.remove(); // MUTATION
}
```

Following this loop, my `trades` collection only contains the relevant trades. But, I have achieved this using *mutation* - a careless programmer *could easily have missed* that `trades` was an input parameter, an instance variable, or is used elsewhere in the method. As such, it is **quite possible their code is now broken**. Furthermore, such code is extremely *brittle for refactoring* for this same reason; a programmer wishing to refactor a piece of code must be very careful to not let mutated collections escape the scope in which they are intended to be used and, vice-versa, that they don't accidentally use an un-mutated collection where they should have used a mutated one.

Compare with Scala:

```
val db = trades filter (_.counterparty == DeutscheBank) //MAPPING INPUT TO OUTPUT
```

This *creates a new collection*! It doesn't affect anyone who is looking at `trades` and is inherently safer.

### Mapping

Suppose I have a `List<Trade>` and I want to get a `Set<Stock>` for the unique stocks which I have been trading. Again, the idiom in Java is to create a collection and *mutate* it.

```
Set<Stock> stocks = new HashSet<Stock>();
for (Trade t : trades) stocks.add(t.getStock()); //MUTATION
```

Using scala the correct thing to do is to map the input collection and then convert to a set:

```
val stocks = (trades map (_.stock)).toSet  //MAPPING INPUT TO OUTPUT
```

Or, if we are concerned about performance:

```
(trades.view map (_.stock)).toSet
(trades.iterator map (_.stock)).toSet
```

What are the advantages here? Well:

1. My code can never observe a partially-constructed result
2. The application of a function `A => B` to a `Coll[A]` to get a `Coll[B]` is clearer.

### Accumulating

Again, in Java the idiom has to be mutation. Suppose we are trying to sum the *decimal* quantities of the trades we have done:

```
BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO
for (Trade t : trades) {
    sum.add(t.getQuantity()); //MUTATION
}
```

Again, we must be very careful not to accidentally observe a partially-constructed result! In scala, we can do this in a single expression:

```
val sum = (0 /: trades)(_ + _.quantity) //MAPPING INTO TO OUTPUT
```

Or the various other forms:

```
(trades.foldLeft(0)(_ + _.quantity)
(trades.iterator map (_.quantity)).sum
(trades.view map (_.quantity)).sum
```

Oh, by the way, **there is a bug in the Java implementation!** *Did you spot it?*

Comment: please do not make the explanation more complicated. I just need how the sentence relates functional behavior.

Comment: Why is this explanation more complicated? I have explained the Java idiom of *mutating data in place* and how the same thing can be achieved in scala by *mapping input to output*, when performing common tasks with collections!

Answer (score 1):

What it means is that if you write [pure functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) like this you always get the same output from the same input, and there are no side effects, which makes it easier to reason about your programs and ensure that they are correct.

so for example the function:

```
def times2(x:Int) = x*2
```

is pure, while

```
def add5ToList(xs: MutableList[Int]) {
    xs += 5
}
```

is impure because it edits data in place as a side effect.  This is a problem because that same list could be in use elsewhere in the the program and now we can't guarantee the behaviour because it has changed.

A pure version would use immutable lists and return a new list

```
def add5ToList(xs: List[Int]) = {
    5::xs
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty examples with collections, which are easy to come by but might give the wrong impression. This concept works at *all levels* of the language (it doesn't at the VM level, however). One example is the case classes. Consider these two alternatives:

```
// Java-style
class Person(initialName: String, initialAge: Int) {
    def this(initialName: String) = this(initialName, 0)
    private var name = initialName
    private var age = initialAge
    def getName = name
    def getAge = age
    def setName(newName: String) { name = newName }
    def setAge(newAge: Int) { age = newAge }
}

val employee = new Person("John")
employee.setAge(40) // we changed the object

// Scala-style
case class Person(name: String, age: Int) {
  def this(name: String) = this(name, 0)
}
val employee = new Person("John")
val employeeWithAge = employee.copy(age = 40) // employee still exists!
```

This concept is applied on the construction of the immutable collection themselves: a `List` never changes. Instead, new `List` objects are created when necessary. Use of persistent data structures reduce the copying that would happen on a mutable data structure.